# Torri not configured warning, when starting ember test?

Tags: ember.js

When I am running: `ember test --filter="acceptance"`, I am getting this warning:

> Torii is installed but not configured in config/environment.js.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Plz provide us more information about the libs you're using. Did you inject the configuration in your test? Frameworks like firebase need this to actually work in testing environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to `config/environment.js`

```
torii: {
  sessionServiceName: 'session'
},
```